# how can you programatically tell if a group header is clicked in a .NET ListView?

Tags: c#, .net

What we're looking to do is determine if a group header has been clicked, like the "Hard Disk Drives" or the "Devices with Removable Storage" headers in the My Computer on Vista/7 screen.  This has to work in XP.

We can detect when a mouse is in the region, and then trap a click, but we'd like to know if there is a specific event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an article that implements a custom ListView control which I believe the author has tackled the problem of clicking on a group [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ObjectListView.aspx). There is another [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/HeaderRightClick.aspx) which shows which header is clicked on although I am not 100% confident if that is in the context of a group header...but I would imagine it would be the same principle for group headers...

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: This is what we're looking for, but our concern with it being under the GPL is that we'll have to release our code under the GPL too.  (With regards to the first article.)   It's just something we're concerned will get us in trouble from legal later :p

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use, hope it will be of help:

```
   Private Sub ListView1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles ListView1.PreviewMouseDown

    If e.LeftButton = MouseButtonState.Pressed Then

        Dim pt As Point = e.GetPosition(Me)
        Dim ListViewComponent As Object = System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(Me, pt)
        If ListViewComponent.visualhit.ToString = "System.Windows.Controls.Border" Then
            ' mouse down event was on header row  
        Else
            ' mouse down event was not on the header row  
        End If
        ListViewComponent = Nothing
        pt = Nothing

    End If

End Sub
```